# Printing on Bluetooth (Version 3.0) iOS using react-native-thermal-receipt-printer

Tags: ios, react-native, printing, bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

I am facing an issue that the Bluetooth Printer (Epson TM-20, Bluetooth 3.0) is not getting recognize by a react native library (https://github.com/HeligPfleigh/react-native-thermal-receipt-printer). Printer gets connected by from the Bluetooth settings (of the iPhone). Printer gets connected from Epson TM Utility App (for iOS & Android).
From my iOS App, on the selection from the Devices list (a screen to show all the Bluetooth devices & select a device to fetch the mac address and make the connectivity), only devices with Bluetooth version is higher than 3.0 (For Ex. my One Plus 11 R mobile) is shown but the mentioned Bluetooth Printer is not.

Answer (score 0):

Here the list of supported printers I suppose: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbZaq.png
However, I'm not sure if this library is able to support them all.
You may test the native Epson SDK that I recently wrapped at https://github.com/tr3v3r/react-native-esc-pos-printer.

It offers a Bluetooth connection as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @pratik-prakash-bindage @user19406764 for your valuable suggestion.
Now a number (instead of the printer name), is shown (along with all other Bluetooth devices) but I am still facing a connectivity issue, if I select **this** number, the printer doesn't work. No error, No exception.